# Isolar processador para executar apenas meu programa

Tags: c, c++, assembly, sistema-operacional, processo

Tem como eu isolar o processador para executar apenas meu programa em C?

É mais uma questão didática e acadêmica passada pelo meu professor de I.A.

Ele pediu para que executássemos milhões de operações de soma de números reais, e pegar o tempo que o processador levou para executá-las. Depois dividir, e achar a media que o processador leva para executar 1 operação de soma.

E fazer isso com as demais operações de subtração, multiplicação e comparação.

Como faço para isolar completamente o processador, e ele executar só meu código? Ele deixou livre pra fazer em qualquer linguagem, mas acredito que C seja a mais viável, pode ser Assembly também.

Se for possível o Windows parar todos os processos pra fazer só aquele calculo, o SO não vai dar pau? E como faço isso?

Comment: Que tal começar por [Escalonamento de Processos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalonamento_de_processos "Escalonamento de Processos").e depois algo mais prático como: [Nice no Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix) "Nice")

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em relacao aos sistemas operacionais GNU/Linux, existe maneiras de se fazer isso sim, basicamente voce tera que usar o `cpuset`.

## Exemplo:

```
$ mkdir /cpuset 
$ mount -t cpuset none /cpuset/
$ cd /cpuset

$ mkdir sys                               # cria um cpuset para o sistema operacional
$ /bin/echo 0-2 > sys/cpuset.cpus         # atribui os cpu cores 0-2
$ /bin/echo 1 > sys/cpuset.cpu_exclusive
$ /bin/echo 0 > sys/cpuset.mems     

$ mkdir rt                                 # cria cpuset para o teu processo
$ /bin/echo 3 > rt/cpuset.cpus             # atribui o cpu core 3

$ /bin/echo 1 > rt/cpuset.cpu_exclusive
$ /bin/echo 0 > rt/cpuset.mems
$ /bin/echo 0 > rt/cpuset.sched_load_balance
$ /bin/echo 1 > rt/cpuset.mem_hardwall

# direciona todos os processos do cpuset default para o cpuset sys
$ for T in `cat tasks`; do echo "Moving " $T; /bin/echo $T > sys/tasks; done
```

Apos essa etapa de configuracao inicie o teu processo (programa) e direcione para o cpuset dedicado recem criado.

```
$ /bin/echo $PID > /cpuset/rt/tasks
```

### Consulte mais [`man cpuset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html).

Answer (score 3):

Isto não é possível em sistemas operacionais "normais", o sistema operacional é que controla isto. O que dá para fazer é pedir alta prioridade para o sistema operacional, que entregará como ele quiser. Dá para determinar afinidade e com isto tentar fazer que o seu processo só rode em um dos processadores, mas isto é discricionário do SO.

Sendo assim pode-se fazer em qualquer linguagem que achar melhor, a única questão é chamar a API do SO que define o agendamento de processos.

Comment: Em sistemas unix, essa prioridade é definido pelo `nice` do programa. Quanto menos bacana, mais prioritário. Eu esqueci qual o nome dado a isso no Windows

Comment: Nem se eu fizer em Assembly ? Já que ele vai estar manipulando diretamente nos registradores ?

Comment: Nada pode passar por cima do sistema operacional. Não é o registrador que controla prioridade de processo, é o sistema operacional.

Comment: @Bruno você pode até obter um `flop` mais alto direto com assembly usando apenas registradores, mas normalmente isso se torna irrelevante porque os usos mais alto nível (como multiplicação de matrizes) requerem usar muita memória de ponto flutuante. Normalmente mais até que o número de registradores

Answer (score 3):

Isso tudo depende do seu SO. Em SO modernos tem APIs que permitem tirar estatísticas de uso do processador, pelo programa. Ou seja, quanto tempo de CPU se gastou exclusivamente para executar o seu programa, quanto tempo ele gastou para executar dentro no *kernel*, quanto tempo ele gastou total, e assim sucessivamente.

Assim, embora vc não tem uso exclusivo da CPU, com essas estatísticas, vc pode contabilizar o uso da CPU, como se ela fosse totalmente do programa.

No mundo UNIX, vc pode usar o [getrusage](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Resource-Usage.html). No caso do Windows, vc pode usar o [GetProcessTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx)